# The access speed for google map api is so slowly in mainland china, how to solve it?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm a python developer in mainland china, my project must use google map api, especially Places API. But i'm Struggling to waiting for a long time when I request that APIs. And I always get "time out".So...is there any way to solve this problem? I'm worry about it. I heard that the url of api in mainland china is like 'ditu.google.cn...' instead 'maps.google.com...', I don't know if it is true.

Comment: The javascript-API is available via ditu.google.cn and loads the most ressources from google.cn. But the requests to the places-service will be sended to googleapis.com, I'm afraid the places-API is not accessible via a chinese host.